# Printing dupes after print dialog has shown no dupes?

Tags: browser, printing, printer, web

I have this strange bug with dupes.

In my software (web application) i have a loop that creates html tables filled with data from my db.
 These tables will represent a layout of  labels that can be printed.

I use CSS to style the tables and i use "page-break-after: always;" to tell the browser where a new label/page is.

To the problem.
When i open the print dialog i can se my labels/pages correctly.
They are numbered from 1 and asc.
But when i do print, the printer sometimes.. totaly random, print.. let´s say nr: 1, 2, 3, 4.. and here it get stuck.. and print label 4 several times (dupes). then it just ends without printing the next labels (5, 6, 7...)

I have searched my code for bugs..but in my world the problem can´t be my web application.. it should be with the printer?

Problem is that it is only my application that causes this error.

Where should i look for bugs/errors?
What can cause this AFTER the print dialog closes and the printing is starting?

Please ask questions and i will update this question so that you can understand what my problem is. (If that´s not clear)

I can paste code if you like, but it´s dynamic and pretty big so i won´t do it in this edit.

Comment: Have you tried it with different printers?

Comment: No it's not possible because the error just occurs in random times.. and it´s a special printer for small labels. I will call the manufator...